# Why facebook redirect with hash not query

Tags: facebook

I've done facebook login.

But redirect uri is weird.

http://mydomain/apis/facebook/callback.php#state=posting&access_token=[MASKED]&expires_in=7060&response_type=token

The problem is parameter not passed with HTTP query string.
So I couldn't get parameter on my server program.
You can see that query is hash(#)

[Correct query started with]

```
?state
```

[But in my case is started with]

```
#state
```

In my memory it was passed with query string originally.
Somethings changed?

Comment: Which return “format” you want, is something you specify via the login dialog parameters ...

Comment: Thank you that problem was '&response_type=token'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is '&response_type=token'

Answer (score 1):

To fix this error just change `response_type=token` to `response_type=code` in your API call.